# AlT R Key In blender opens Windows Run command

Tags: windows

When I use the alt R key in Windows 10 Pro it opens the Windows run command. How do I fix this?

Comment: Up to this point Run menu in Windows is opened with Win+R. Are you sure you press Alt+R and you didn't change anything with system configuration?

Comment: Mr Zac - I am pressing alt +R but it opens the windows 10 pro run command. I have found that if I change the Key in Blender to alt Gr +R it works. Thank you for your assistance.